# Subir arquivos para ambiente de produção

Tags: php

Quando vamos subir um ambiente para produção em um servidor, hospedagem padrão, via ftp ou ssh. 
Qual a ferramente usar para que subam apenas os arquivos necessários à aplicação, sem ter que subir testes, documentação, etc.

Eu uso php

Obrigado

Comment: http://github.com ou para privados http://bitbucket.org

Comment: O projeto está hospedado numa hospedagem padrão compartilhada ou cloud/vps/dedicated server?

Answer (score 1):

As ferramentas mais comuns para tal tarefa são os controladores de versões.

Os mais populares são o GIT e Subversion, também conhecido como "SVN".

O GIT oferece o repositório público no site github.com. Há também os planos para hospedagem de repositórios privados.

Alternativamente, é possível instalar um servidor Git dentro de um ambiente privado, no seu próprio servidor, por exemplo. Dessa forma não ficaria dependente de serviços terceiros.

O Subversion é um concorrente mais antigo do git. O manuseio é mais simples e também amplamente aceito, apesar de existir controvérsias que o pejorativam em relação ao Git.

Para os que não tem condições de instalar o git ou subversion no servidor de hospedagem (normalmente em hospedagem compartilhada), tem que fazer manualmente mesmo ou criar scripts ou softwares por conta própria.

Há alguns softwares comerciais no mercado e também iniciativas open-source como essas:

https://github.com/tipui/Tipui-GIT-FTP

https://github.com/myflowpl/git-ftp

Se buscar no google, "php git ftp" encontrará alguns outros.

Esse primeiro é de minha autoria. "Tipui GIT FTP".

Há mais de 2 anos que não mexo com esses códigos, mas funciona bem.

Há certos bugs como por exemplo, falta tratamentos de erros principalmente quando há algum erro no envio de um arquivo. Também falta um meio de continuar um upload interrompido.

Outra deficiência é falta de suporte a SFTP, ou seja, FTP sob SSL.

Todo o código é escrito em PHP usando funções PHP FTP http://php.net/ftp

Quando eu tiver algum ânimo voltarei a brincar com esse projeto.